# Target class [App\http\Controllers\MarfilController] does not exist. Error

Tags: class, laravel-8

Error

```
Target class [App\http\Controllers\MarfilController] does not exist.
```

My Laravel 8x Project is running on localhost but when I publish it I get this error.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::redirect('/', 'tr');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'  ], function(){
      Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
      });
      Route::get('/hakkimizda', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@hakkimizda')->name('hakkimizda');
      Route::get('/iletisim', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@iletisim')->name('iletisim');
      Route::get('/kunye', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@kunye')->name('kunye');
      Route::get('/sikayet', 'App\http\Controllers\HizmetlerController@sikayet')->name('sikayet');
      Route::get('/garanti', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@sikayet')->name('garanti');
      Route::get('/kalite', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@kalite')->name('kalite');
      Route::get('/teklifal', 'App\http\Controllers\HizmetlerController@teklifal')->name('teklifal');
      Route::get('/urunler', 'App\http\Controllers\ProductController@product')->name('urunler');
      Route::get('/detail/{slug}', 'App\http\Controllers\ProductController@detail')->name('detail');
      Route::get('/sil/{id}', 'App\http\Controllers\AdminController@deleteLink')->name('deletelink');
      Route::get('/', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@index')->name('index');
      Route::get('/test', 'App\http\Controllers\MarfilController@test')->name('test');
      Route::get('/dil-ekle/{slug}', 'App\http\Controllers\AdminController@dilekle')->name('dil-ekle');
      Route::post('/dil-ekle/ekle', 'App\http\Controllers\AdminController@dileklendi')->name('dil-eklendi');
      Route::get('/kategori/{slug}' , 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@category')->name('listele');
      Route::post('/image/add' , 'App\Http\Controllers\ImageController@addimage')->name('addimage');
      Route::get('/delete/image/{id}' ,App\Http\Controllers\ImageController@deleteImage')->name('deleteimage');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
      Voyager::routes();
});
```

Comment: There's new Syntax for Laravel 8's routing, it no longer uses `ExampleController@exampleMethod`, but rather `[ExampleController::class, 'exampleMethod']`, see the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files, and you need to add `use App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController;` to the top of your code.

Comment: My project works fine locally, but I'm getting the same error again on live.. web site link http://www.marfilfiltre.com/tr

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
use App\http\Controllers\MarfilController;
```

after the <?php tag in web.php file. Made this for all the related controller declared in this file.

Comment: My project works fine locally, but I'm getting the same error again on live.. web site link marfilfiltre.com/tr

Answer (score 0):

The hosting company fixed the problem. Thanks